# Error in base64EncodeInvalid length for a Base-64 char array or string

Tags: c#

I want to decode some string by using following C# code:

```
public static string deCodeStdXML(string encodeXML)
{
    string str2;
    try
    {
        byte[] data = System.Convert.FromBase64String(encodeXML);
        str2 = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        throw new Exception("Error in base64Encode" + exception.Message);
    }
    return str2;
}
```

but when I test it with long string, it doesn't work, see below:

```
string encodeXML = @"H4sIAAAAAAAEAOy9B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mkuwdaUcjKasqgcplVmVdZhZAzO2dvPfee++999577733ujudTif33/8/XGZkAWz2zkrayZ4hgKrIHz9+fB8/Il5mdbvM6/SLvGmyizx9lU/z4jKf/czLYpWXxTL/md/7i+f64ZNs8abOpm+L5cXPPH69+HKVL39yL323KJfNo3fN7LOP5m27enT37tXV1fjq3riqL";
string result = deCodeStdXML(encodeXML);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

it throws exception:

```
System.Exception was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233088
  Message=Error in base64EncodeInvalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.
  Source=HarnessDBLayer
  StackTrace:
       at HarnessDBLayer.DBHelper.deCodeStdXML(String encodeXML) in c:\Users\zhanzhex\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\XMLValidation\HarnessDBLayer\DBLayer.cs:line 602
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.TEST_deCodeStdXML() in c:\Users\zhanzhex\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\XMLValidation\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 43
       at ConsoleApplication1.Program.Main(String[] args) in c:\Users\zhanzhex\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\XMLValidation\ConsoleApplication1\Program.cs:line 22
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

can anybody tell me how to fix this issue?

Comment: Well, that's simply not a valid base64 string. It's 257 characters long. It needs padding to be valid base64... where did you get it from to start with? As an aside, your try/catch block is worse than pointless - it's removing the stack trace that would be useful. Just get rid of it, and turn your method into a two line method...

Answer (score 1):

Your string is not a valid [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) string.
Check above link for more informations about base64.

You can easily check this by counting the string length:

```
Console.WriteLine("H4sIAAAAAAAEAOy9B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mkuwdaUcjKasqgcplVmVdZhZAzO2dvPfee++999577733ujudTif33/8/XGZkAWz2zkrayZ4hgKrIHz9+fB8/Il5mdbvM6/SLvGmyizx9lU/z4jKf/czLYpWXxTL/md/7i+f64ZNs8abOpm+L5cXPPH69+HKVL39yL323KJfNo3fN7LOP5m27enT37tXV1fjq3riqL".Length);
```

this will output value "257" so as you can see from the wikipedia page it is not valid beacuse of it's length. :)

Hope that will help you.